# Медленная работа phpmyadmin на хост-машине | Vagrant

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, vagrant

Здравствуйте.
Пробрасываю порт из VM Vagrant в хост-машину так:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 3309, guest: 3306
```

Далее комментирую

```
skip-external-locking
bind-address
```

в /etc/mysql/my.cnf (на VM)

На хост-машине в /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php добавил:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3309';
$i++;
```

Таким образом на логин-панеле phpmyadmin появляется выбор хоста к которому коннектиться. Все бы ничего, вот только жуткие тормоза на хост-машине. Один раз после редеплоя виртуалки все летало на ура, но это было один раз.
В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. Возможно дал не полную информацию для помощи, не уверен.

**UPD:**

```
phpMyAdmin: v4.0.10deb1
Версия сервера: 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Версия клиента базы данных: libmysql - 5.5.49
```

**UPD 2**

```
Ось: Linux Ubuntu (64-bit)
ОЗУ: 2048мб
Чипсет: PIIX3
Процессор: 1
Предел загрузки ЦПУ: 100%
Ускорение -> аппаратная виртуализация:
 * вкл VT-x/AMD-V
 * вкл Nested Paging
```

**Uptime в момент тормозов:**

```
08:14:54 up 13 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.04
```

**Free в момент тормозов:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2049980     778068    1271912       9640      14136     164160
-/+ buffers/cache:     599772    1450208
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Расшарена папка **/var/www** с хост-машины в **/path/to/project/www** (в моем случае это **/vagrant/www**). Внутри phpMyAdmin'а нет.

Comment: Если не сложно сообщите параметры вашей виртуальной машины, а так же выполните на ней команды uptime и free в момент начала томозов (если не сложно, прикрепите результаты к вопросу). Используются ли расшаренные папки и не лежит ли в такой папке phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @cheops, благодарю за отклик. 
Информацию прикрепил в UPD 2. Может быть неверно понял вопрос про параметры системы. (не те данные, которые Вы хотели бы видеть). Не совсем понял, что именно нужно было скинуть.

Answer (score 1):

Обновил phpMyAdmin до 4.5.5

После **vagrant destroy && vagrant up** начало нормально работать (halt не помог).
Так изменился вот этот показатель:

```
Версия сервера: 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
```